# Have an application launch on top of the Start Screen on Windows 8 boot

Tags: .net, windows-8, kiosk

I have an app much like a kiosk app that requires it load up directly from boot into fullscreen. I use the "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run" setting and it works well in Windows 7.

It still works in Windows 8 but is blocked by the start screen and you need to switch to the desktop manually to see the fullscreen display.

Is there any setting I can use for Windows 8 that will bypass the start screen so my app loads fullscreen at boot? I prefer something like the above registry setting that I can toggle on/off in my application options and keeps the rest of the desktop available.

Comment: Second hit from a quick google for "windows 8 disable start screen": http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/bypass-windows-8-start-screen-to-jump-directly-to-desktop-on-startup/